# Android Library: Is it possible to pass an Intent into my Library to retrieve the ParcelableExtra's

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nfc

I want to use the ParcelableExtra function of an Intent to retrieve an android.nfc.Tag Object

```
nfcTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
```

In the newIntent function this code works. But now I want to write an Android Library which uses the same android.nfc.Tag Object.

Is it possible and state of the art to pass an Intent into an Android Library?

Answer (score 0):

It is not "state of the art" to pass an Intent object to a library, while this might be technically possible because because an Intent is just an instance of a standard type Java class that can be passed between methods whether inside the App code or in a library.

The reason why you should not uses the Intent Object is because the newer and better NFC API of `enableReaderMode` does not use `Intent`s it just gets passed the `Tag` Java Object directly when a Tag is discovered.
Thus it is better for your library to accept a `Tag` object as input as then it could be used with the older and newer (better) NFC API's

Comment: Perfekt, thank you! Going to pass the Tag Object directly to the Library

Comment: Is it possible to create an Intent in the Android Library itself and retrieve the Tag Object?So the main app doesn't need to handle this part of the code.

Comment: No, an Intent is only received by the Activity, you can then pass it on to whatever you want.